# Understanding numeric_only boolean parameter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to better understand the use of the numeric_only parameter.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the goal is to pull the median number of video shares by the author's ban status. Why do I need to specify "numeric_only = True" within the median function. Why do the results pull multiple fields of the data frame when I remove the numeric_only parameter?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icmZ2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2wFu.png)

I would expect that by just using median(['video_share_count']) would be enough to specify that I am interested in pulling only the specific numeric field.

Comment: I would take a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.median.html) and ask why you think you can pass `['video_share_count']` as a parameter. It doesn't seem to support using it this way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"*Why do the results pull multiple fields of the data frame when I remove the numeric_only parameter?*"

[`groupby.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.median.html) only accepts one parameter: `numeric_only`.

By running:

```
df.groupby('author_ban_status').median(['video_share_count'])
```

You're actually still using the `numeric_only` parameter, it's equivalent to:

```
df.groupby('author_ban_status').median(numeric_only=['video_share_count'])
```

And since `bool(['video_share_count'])` evaluates to `True`, you're essentially running:

```
df.groupby('author_ban_status').median(numeric_only=True)
```

So not filtering any column.

You might just want:

```
df.groupby('author_ban_status')[['video_share_count']].median(numeric_only=True)
```